# porting NDIS 5 based IM driver for 802.1x to NDIS 6

Tags: windows, winapi, device-driver, ndis

I have an NDIS 5 based IM driver and a virtual miniport driver for 802.1X VPN connectivity.
It works fine on Windows 7 / Windows 8 but it is not working on windows 10 as the driver is broken.
I was suggested to port the driver to NDIS 6 so that it will work fine on windows 10.

I'm not sure how to decide on which type of driver to choose on NDIS 6 based platform (not sure that miniport driver is needed to be developed or not), As NDIS 5 based IM drivers are replaced with LWF filter drivers on NDIS 6 and there is no need to develop the functions which are going to interface Protocol as well as miniport.

Is it enough to port only the IM driver and leave the miniport driver so that 802.1x based  features work fine?

I have a partial implementation of NDIS 6 LWF driver it works for layer3 connectivity but it is not working for 802.1x. (the resources available online are confusing . Few suggests that NDIS LWF would work fine and few people are saying that LWF don't have CoNDIS support and it won't work)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't port one component of network stack to `NDIS6` and leave the others in `NDIS5` - they won't bind, APIs and even functionality isn't the same. If you port IM, you must port the corresponding miniport as well.

Comment: Thanks @SomeWittyUsername for your reply, I have a question , Is it possible to implement the functionality of 802.1X client using NDIS LWF alone? assume that I'm starting from the scratch and leaving the older NDIS5 implementation, I'm confused with the information from internet resources. I'm asking this question to you because I don't want to research further on this and confuse myself.

Comment: Could you please recommend a sample code on NDIS6 for 802.1x client?

Comment: @Ramesh Sorry, can't answer that for sure. My guess would be that you can implement it as LWF, but you better ask at MSFT driver dev forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/home?forum=wdk